# Is it possible to share some controllers, views and images across multiple website projects in visual studio 2013

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, dependency-injection

I can create websites that use shared C# libraries.  I like this approach because it allows me to change the c# libraries and easily deploy the the changes to my customer's websites.

But now I'm finding that it would be very useful to have some controllers, views and images that I can share across multiple websites. In this way, as before, I can make changes and quickly and easily deploy them to all my clients.

Could someone please tell me if this is possible?

Answer (score 0):

Any controller (implementing System.Web.Controller) that resides in an assembly in your bin folder will be considered, you do not need to do anything for this.

For Views you could use RazorGenerator: https://www.nuget.org/packages/RazorGenerator.Mvc/